# String replacement using split and map not working on Firefox in Unix

Tags: javascript, unix, firefox, unicode, utf-8

everyone, I got you a bug that I'm not able to fix at all.

The explanation is: I've made a pipe to use in my Angular 6/Material 2 project that should clean the string typed in a textarea.

The test/pipe is running here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-glitched-unix-firefox

What it does:
1 - based on a charmap, replaces characters like `éèêë` by it's raw version `e`.
2 - then removes any chacarter that doesn't belongs to the specified regex: `` /[^a-zA-Z0-9 \-"#$%&'()*+,.;:<=>?!@/[\]\\^_`{|}~]/g ``

Ex.: changes `érick` by `erick` or `♥` by `love`

The bug is: In WINDOWS, doesn't matter the browser 
(tested in Chrome, IE and Firefox) it works. When I test in UNIX it works in Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox. Instead of doing what it should do it empties the textarea itself.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, not THE solution, but it's a solution.

Isntead of using `(ngModelChange)` I'm using `(keyup)` calling the pipe from inside of it. This way, the infinite loop that was happening doesn't happen anymore. (Yeah, I've found the infinite loop after I posted the question)

I assumed the the bug was the way the Browser was dealing with the infinity loop. Chrome was just canceling it and Firefox was removing the data that was causing it.

Exemple of the solution:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-glitched-unix-firefox-fix